# Maximising the trace of the observability Gramian

Tags: control-theory

Suppose I have a matrix W. This matrix has an observability Gramian Q. Is there a way to see which changes in the matrix W will maximise the trace of Q? Is there a natural way to express maximising Q as a function of the entries of W?

Thanks!!

Comment: I assume that your $W$ and $Q$ are equivalent to $C^\top C$ and $W_O$ respectively as [defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability_Gramian#Observability_Gramian)? Also what constraint do you put on $W$ because otherwise you could just multiply that by a really large number such that (the trace of) $Q$ would increase as well.

Comment: Yes, with this definition W would be A, Q would be Wo and C would be the identity matrix in my case. Of course you can manipulate the trace by multiplying, what I would like to know is if there is way to see how you can increase the trace of Q by changing the entries of W (or A with the wiki notation). It's a function of the exponential map with respect to W, and the derivative is a pain for gradient ascend (unless I am completely wrong about this?), so was wondering if there is another way to tackle this.